# Why do formal mathematical definitions of map projections define x and y in terms of phi and theta?

Tags: coordinate-system

On Wikipedia all of the projections are mathematically defined in a form like `x = f(phi,theta)`.

Is there a reason that this is used instead of `phi = f(x,y)` ?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 1):

phi = f(x,y) would be a formula for the inverse projection, converting from the 2D x,y plane to the equivalent latitude location.

Answer (score 0):

A map projection is a mapping from the surface of the earth to a flat map. Formally, the function describing the mapping could be represented using any well-defined coordinate system for the domain (earth surface) and codomain (flat map). It so happens that (latitude,longitude) and (x,y) are the most natural ones.

As another answer says, going the other way would be the inverse of the projection function. Also a valid thing to want to know, and generally provided nearby in descriptive texts, but formally that's a different function.

Incidentally, the projection function can technically be defined in any unambiguous way. Therefore, sufficiently precise descriptions of projections via e.g. secant cones or cylinders could be viewed as alternate function definitions. It is merely that the default parametrization of the surface of the earth is indeed (latitude,longitude), not something equally theoretically valid like "east-west angular displacement versus the central meridian of UTM zone 18N" instead of longitude.

This glosses over some details regarding the geoid, altitudes, etc.; I'm focusing on the gist of your question, I hope.